# Parsing a nested JSON in a react component in a dynamic variable which can fill the table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I need to parse a nested JSON, where I need to pass the headers to a header variable and data values in the table variable, in order to get a table. But while parsing through the table I'm getting the error as given below. This is a response I'm getting from the backend, or how can I change this JSON, to a way which is convenient for use?

Here's the code I'm using.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const jsonData = [
  {
    name: 'John',
    age: 30,
    address: [
      {
        street: '123 Main St',
        city: 'New York',
        state: 'NY',
        zipcode: '10001',
      },
    ],
    phone: [
      {
        type: 'home',
        number: '123-456-7890',
      },
      {
        type: 'work',
        number: '111-222-3333',
      },
    ],
    email: ['john@example.com', 'john.doe@example.com'],
  },
];

const App = () => {
  const [rows, setRows] = useState([]);

  const data = jsonData[0];
  const keys = Object.keys(data);
  const values = Object.values(data);

  const rowsData = keys.map((key, index) => {
    return {
      key: key,
      value: Array.isArray(values[index])
        ? values[index].join(', ')
        : values[index],
    };
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    setRows(rowsData);
  }, []);

  return (
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Key</th>
          <th>Value</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {rows.map((row, index) => (
          <tr key={index}>
            <td>{row.key}</td>
            <td>{row.value}</td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};

export default App;
```

The output I'm getting is,
[image: The out for the code]

Comment: Surely you want all of John's data in one row so you can add someone else's data in the next row etc?

Comment: Yes, there are more Johns in the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

This was achieved by, destructuring the JSON. Updated code is below, with added styles.

```
import React from 'react';
import './style.css';

const jsonData = [
  {
    name: 'John',
    age: 30,
    address: [
      {
        street: '123 Main St',
        city: 'New York',
        state: 'NY',
        zipcode: '10001',
      },
    ],
    phone: [
      {
        type: 'home',
        number: '123-456-7890',
      },
      {
        type: 'work',
        number: '111-222-3333',
      },
    ],
    email: ['john@example.com', 'john.doe@example.com'],
  },
];

const App = () => {
  const [firstItem] = jsonData;

  const { name, age, address, phone, email } = firstItem;
  const [firstAddress] = address;
  const [homePhone, workPhone] = phone;
  const [firstEmail, secondEmail] = email;

  const tableStyle = {
    borderCollapse: 'collapse',
    width: '100%',
    margin: '20px auto',
    fontFamily: 'Menlo',
    fontSize: '14px',
    width: '80vw',
  };

  const thStyle = {
    backgroundColor: '#f2f2f2',
    padding: '8px',
    textAlign: 'left',
    width: '40px',
  };

  const tdStyle = {
    border: '1px solid #ddd',
    padding: '8px',
    textAlign: 'left',
    width: '1000px',
  };

  return (
    <table style={tableStyle}>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th style={thStyle}>Key : </th>
          <th style={thStyle}>Value</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {Object.entries({
          Name: name,
          Age: age,
          Address: `${firstAddress.street}, ${firstAddress.city}, ${firstAddress.state} (${firstAddress.zipcode})`,
          'Phone (Home)': homePhone.number,
          'Phone (Work)': workPhone.number,
          Email: `${firstEmail}, ${secondEmail}`,
        }).map(([key, value]) => (
          <tr key={key}>
            <td style={tdStyle}>{key} :</td>
            <td style={tdStyle}>{value}</td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};

export default App;
```